# concatenate all .csv files in a directory including the file name and control the data format

Tags: powershell, concatenation

I have a bit of code in powershell I took from the internet (I'm quite new to powershell) to concatenate all .csv files in my directory including the file name.  However, the output file format is not what I want.  I want this in my output file:

```
filename
data1
data2
data3
etc
```

Instead I get this:

```
filename
data1 data2 data3 etc
```

My original .csv files were in this format:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
dir $csvFilesPath\*.csv | ForEach {
    $variable = "$($_.Name)`n$(Get-content $_.FullName)"
    Add-Content -Value $variable -Path $csvFilesPath\output.txt
}
```

After learning a bit about the suggestions from others I was able to use this code to achieve something I can use:
'''
    # This bit of code goes through all the csv files and adds the file name 
    to each row in each file under a new column called filename

```
Get-ChildItem "$csvFilesPath\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
   $CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName -Delimiter ","
   $FileName = $_.Name

$CSV | Select-Object *,@{N='Filename';E={$FileName}} | Export-CSV 
$_.FullName -NTI -Delimiter ","
}

# this code gets all of the .csv files and concatenates all of them into 
an output.csv file

import-csv (Get-ChildItem $csvFilesPath\*.csv)  | export-csv 
$csvFilesPath\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

'''
Thanks all for your help!

Comment: CSV files are flat _horizontal_ files. [*grin*] they have ROWS of data where each column is on field in the row. so ... what is the layout of the source CSV files? what you show is not a full CSV file since it lacks a header row AND lacks and other columns. your data looks like a simple text file ...

Comment: Consider using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` instead of  `Get-Content` and `Add-Content`…

Comment: HI Lee - The csv file is like I wrote above.  It has 2 columns and several rows depending on the file length.  The data is on separate lines.  It appears that my concatenation script is dropping out the carriage returns.

Comment: @ccasey27 this probably happened due to you using `Get-Content`. Follow what @JosefZ said

Comment: @ccasey27 - your sample data shows only ONE column with 3 data rows and no header row ... so where is the 2nd column?

Comment: What are the two columns? Do they have headers? Without knowing your data format, it's not possible to understand what you need.

Comment: Here is an example of the csv file.  The V and I are the header.  I want the name of the file to appear before each concatenated file.   V I
0 -1.83E-12
1 -9.61E-13
2 -5.14E-13
3 -1.80E-13
4 1.85E-13

Comment: I tried using import-csv and export-csv and the results are close to something I can use.  The only problem is the file name that's added includes the full path.  Is there something I can add to this code to get only the file name?    dir $csvFilesPath\*.csv | ForEach {
    $filename = $_
    import-csv -path $filename |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Filename' -Value $filename -PassThru
    } |

    Export-Csv -Path $csvFilesPath\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate your achievements (and their effects as well) - instead of adding them in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work for you. There are a couple things to note.

1. All of your Csvs will have to have the same headers.
2. If you update the files to include the FileName column, this script will fail any subsequent runs. You would have to edit the NoteProperty instead of adding it.

> ```
> # Make a list for storing the variables. There is no point to access them twice.
> [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$contentsList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
>
> # Get-ChildItem and dir do the same thing
> Get-ChildItem "$csvFilesPath\*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
>    # Importing the Csv
>    $CSV = Import-CSV -Path $_.FullName
>
>    # Add the FileName NoteProperty. This is what powershell turns your Csv headers into.
>    $CSV | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FileName -NotePropertyValue $_.Name
>
>    # Add every row of the current csv file to the contentsList variable
>    $contentsList.AddRange($CSV)
>
>    # Export the current csv back to it's original location.
>    # This is done to add the FileName column.
>    # If you don't want to add that column to the actual files, then just comment out the line below.
>    $CSV | Export-Csv -Path $_.FullName -NoTypeInformation
> }
>
> # Finally take the contentsList variable and export it to your csv output file
> $contentsList | Export-Csv "$csvFilesPath\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
> ```